# Why does visual studio not run current html file

Tags: html, visual-studio

I am currently designing a website using Visual Studio 2015 Community and, for whatever reason, when I launch the website it will not launch the most current html file. Even though I have saved the newest file it will launch a previously created version of the website. Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Are you saying that you want to launch a page other than the homepage, or are you saying that you're editing the homepage and saving it but it's displaying a previous version?

Comment: what type of project are you working on? is it an MVC project? Web Forms? or is it just a collection of html and javascript files?

Comment: I am launching the homepage and is displaying a previous version. And currently the project is just a collection of Html, Javascript, and css files.

Comment: A guess: it's not VS, but the browser that is serving the file from it's cache. Use `F5` or `Ctrl+F5` to refresh.

Comment: Hans Kesting- I am using both of those commands with no luck.

Comment: Have you tried using another browser? I've found Microsoft Edge to be fidgety with refreshing.

Comment: I was using Google Chrome

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the current html page is inside the project(from solution explorer).
If you make a new file from 'File' menu it will not be saved inside your project.
To create file inside project write click Proj name(in solution explorer) and click add -> file

Answer (score 0):

In solution explorer right click on your **project** then select **properties**

after that from left panel select **web**

from there you can see three radio buttons inside **start actions** select **current page** 
(or the option that suits you)